# Break the Object.keys loop based on count

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to break the loop once first 3 objects are iterated. I could have variable set for count and do increment on map with filter but is there a graceful way to do it?

```
Object.keys(data)
    .filter(key => !data[key].required)
    .map(function (key) {
          return <Greetings/>
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could slice before mapping to iterate just over first three elements.

```
Object.keys(data)
    .filter(key => !data[key].required)
    .slice(0, 3)
    .map(function (key) {
          return <Greetings/>
    });
```